# Find closest hidden element and show it with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to show an element, but I have to take care, that the element is visible.
It is possible that the element is nested in different cases and ways (div, span, i ...).

So I want to find the closest element for the destination which is not visible and change it.

I tried it in this way, but I failed:

```
//info: result.msg_target_id = '#myid'
$(result.msg_target_id).closest(':hidden').show();
```

Is it possible to use closest only with ":hidden" - without div, span, i etc.?

What did I do wrong, or which is the best way to do it?

update
Here is the HTML part, but please not, that is only one possible HTML situation, its unknown in which html situation the function above is in use.

```
<div id="modal_errormsg_div" class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible hide">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                    <h5><i class="icon fa fa-ban"></i><span id="modal_errormsg_head"> <?= trans('error')?></span></h5>
                    <span id="modal_errormsg_body"></span>
                  </div>
```

Update
In the meantime I tried these ways, but all failed too.

```
$(result.msg_target_id).prevAll(':hidden:first').show();
```

```
$(result.msg_target_id).prevAll(':hidden:first').removeClass('hide');
```

```
$(result.msg_target_id).siblings(':hidden').show();
```

```
$(result.msg_target_id).siblings(':hidden').removeClass('hide');
```

Comment: can you show your html ?

Comment: i've update one sample

Comment: Not sure if this is what you need can you try like this `$("#myid").prevAll(':hidden:first').show();` . Working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/4k09vjcb/)

Comment: @Swati i've trie it but it dosen't work for me, the part is still invisible (display:none) maybe the "hide" class can caused the problem?

Comment: Then how about this `$("#myid").prevAll(".hide:first").addClass('show').removeClass('hide')` .Working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y4ocp5hf/)

Comment: no, it also wont work and it should work better for the visible and hidden state and not only on the hide class.
Is there no way to search for a next element by the visible/hide state?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223581/discussion-between-swati-and-marc-78).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on @Swati here is the way to solve this

```
$("#myid-inside").show()//show first the divs whose id is there
$("#myid-inside").parent(".hide:first").addClass('show').removeClass('hide') //use parent because the outer div is parent of inner .

//if the div which you need to display is at same level i.e :  
//<div id="myid-outside" class="hide">
//<p id="myid-inside1" style="display:none;">Show me</p>
 // <p id="myid-inside" style="display:none;">Show me</p>
//</div>
//here `myid-inside1` is on same level so use sibilings ..or prevAll else if its not in same level use parent .
```